# VSCode syntax for keydown recognition

Tags: visual-studio, keydown

I have a line of code that works great!
If e.Key = Key.Return Then

I'd like to also look for Control+Return, but cannot figure out the right combination for the Key.+Return Then

Please help.

Comment: where in the VSC code do you want to detect `Ctrl+Return`

Comment: My apologies for such a long response.  Thank you for getting back to me, but I was temporarily assigned another task that consumed my time and attention.  I just recently got back to this coding effort and wold still like to figure this out.  I do not understand the request where in the VSC code...  Do you mean what type of file is it in?  .xaml or .vb or ???

Comment: why do you tag it with VSC if you have a VBasic problem

Comment: It is a Visual Studio question.  I have code where I cannot find where Ctrl+Return are assigned.  I can't find it anywhere in the folder that hold the code.